# Load Balancing Via Virtual IP

Tags: windows, load, load-balancing

I have searched before writing this ... All i found is at certain point they are using load balancer hardware or software. But the thing i need is without hardware and Software can we do the load balancing ?.

While i was searching for this i came across the below statement.

"Another way to distribute requests is to have a single virtual IP (VIP) that all clients use.  And for the computer on that 'virtual' IP to forward the request to the real servers"

Could you please anyone let me know how to do the Virtual IP load balancing?.

I have searched lots of article but i could not find anything related to VIP configuration or setup. All i found is only theoretical materials.

I need to divide the incoming requests into two applications. In this case both application server should be up and running.

Below is the architecture:

Application Node 1 : 10.66.204.10
Application Node 2 : 10.66.204.11

Virtual IP: 10.66.204.104

Comment: If it's a server on an IP doing load balancing there's nothing virtual about it. That's literally what a gateway is for - redistributing requests and responding quickly to balance them.

Comment: its not a physical server. If i am about to use that Virtual IP as GW, how do i configure that...

Comment: You're using a cloud instanced gateway? Where is your instance hosted? This is the part that's confusing me: But the thing i need is without hardware and Software can we do the load balancing ?

Comment: All the instance are in hosted in Virtual machine only. The question u asked --> Yes i read in that article , "we can do the load balancing using virtual IP", thats y i asked.

Answer (score 0):

Run an instance of Nginx and use it as a load balancing Gateway for connections. There's no difference using virtual IPs to actual IPs - although it helps if your cloud setup is on LAN based IPs for both security and ease.

Depending on your setup there's two paths to go:

1. Dynamically assign connections to a server. This can be done on a split (evenly distributed) or on one instance until it fills up - then overflow.
2. Each function has it's own IP assigned. For example, you can configure the Gateway to serve static content itself and request dynamic content from other servers.

Configuring Nginx is a large job. However, it's a relatively well documented process and it shouldn't be hard for you to find a guide that suits your needs.